# What is the correct way to update a record using hibernate, changes are not reflected in db?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have the following mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.jurnil.db.hibernate.Order" table="order_table">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="id">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="shippingTotal">
        <column name="shipping_total" not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <one-to-one name="shippingInfo" class="com.jurnil.db.hibernate.OrderShipping" cascade="all">
  </one-to-one> </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am trying to retrieve existing “order” from DB modify some of the values in order and update them back to DB.

Following is the DAO method I have:

```
public boolean updateOrder(Order o) {
    Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = getTransaction(s);
    o.setUpdated(new Date());
    s.saveOrUpdate(o);
    tryCommit(tx);
    return true;
```

And I call the `orderDAO.updateOrder(order);`

The changes are not reflected in database, and in the hibernate logs i can see `Duplicate entry '332' for key 'PRIMARY'`

When i try to rewrite the session in `updateOrder` function as

```
Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

`s.saveOrUpdate(o);` give me the following error, `Duplicate entry '332' for key 'PRIMARY'`

After trying the suggestion @Guillaume

**changed DAO Method:**

```
public boolean updateOrder(BigDecimal cartTotal, OrderShipping shippingInformation, BigDecimal taxes,
            BigDecimal orderTotal, BigDecimal shippingTotal, Long id) {
        Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = getTransaction(s);
        Order order = (Order) s.load(Order.class, id);
        order.setCartTotal(cartTotal);
        order.setShippingInfo(shippingInformation);
        order.setTaxPaid(taxes);
        order.setTotalPaid(orderTotal);
        order.setShippingTotal(shippingTotal);
        order.getShippingInfo().setOrder(order);
        order.setUpdated(new Date());
        tryCommit(tx);
        return true;
    }
```

**The data is not updated still in DB, In the SQL Logs i can see the transaction is rolling back, why that happens ?**

Below is the SQL logs

```
[2020-09-17 17:45:44,125] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader - Done entity load : com.jurnil.db.hibernate.Order#335
[2020-09-17 17:45:44,126] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - committing
[2020-09-17 17:45:44,126] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
[2020-09-17 17:45:44,135] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: 335, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.jurnil.db.hibernate.OrderShipping#335]
[2020-09-17 17:45:44,136] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - rolling back
```

Comment: What's the error that `s.saveOrUpdate(o);` throws?

Comment: @AlexZuroff I get the following erroe: Duplicate entry '332' for key 'PRIMARY', in both case it is same error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this a new or a legacy application? Are you using Spring or another container service?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yes this is kind a old application still uses hibernate - 4.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Order` object needs to be associated with the same session as the session you're using for the transaction. For instance if you want to update the order with id #322:

```
Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = getTransaction(s);
Order o = s.load(Order.class, 322);
o.setUpdated(new Date());
tryCommit(tx);
```

Note that the `saveOrUpdate` was removed: when the transaction is committed, Hibernate will see that the Order was modified and update the database.

Comment: I tried the suggestion, the data is not updated still. In the SQL Logs i can see the transaction getting rolled back why that happens ? edit the post with this .

Comment: When i print the trace : org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.jurnil.db.hibernate.OrderShipping#335]

Comment: Your OrderShipping object was probably associated with another Session, how did you load it? You need all of these objects to be associated with the same session.

Comment: Order and OrderShipping are one-to-one mapped, i did not load "OrderShipping"  separate. when i change cascade from all to merge, the update happens successfully but no more inserting child record